# When submitting a list object through an HTML form in ASP.Net Core MVC, can the indices be non-consecutive?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, html-helper

I have created a form in ASP.Net Core using a dynamic table where the user can add and delete rows. Each row is a being bound to a collection item in the model, e.g., expenses[0], expenses[1], expenses[2], etc. The user can delete any row, so, for example, the user could delete expenses[1], and then the submitted items would be expenses[0] and expenses[2].

Theoretically, this should work - not only theoretically, but the items are correctly being submitted in the HttpContext.Request.Form. However, anything beyond the deleted index gets dropped before it is bound to the model. So, if expenses[1] gets deleted, ONLY expenses[0] will get bound to the model.

This seems like it could possibly be a library bug or limitation. I am aware of the workarounds (re-indexing the rows or creating a controller function to remove hidden items), but I am interested if anyone has a solution to the core of the problem.

The form is being defined as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "Finance", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.ClaimsTest);
```

Answer (score 0):

> When submitting a list object through an HTML form in ASP.Net Core MVC, can the indices be non-consecutive?
>
>  **Answer:**  No

I think the crux of the problem is that the collection items need to be re-indexed before the form is submitted so that the indexes are contiguous (e.g. `expenses[0]`, `expenses[1]`, `expenses[2]`, etc..)

**My test code**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "MyViewModel Page";
}
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "Finance", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div id="expense-container">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Expenses.Count; i++)
        {
            <div>
                <label>Expense @(i + 1):</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Expenses[i].Name)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Expenses[i].Id)
                <button type="button" class="delete-btn" data-index="@i">Delete</button>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        // JavaScript/jQuery code to handle delete button click event and re-indexing
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".delete-btn").click(function () {
                var index = $(this).data("index");

                // Remove the expense field from the form
                var nameInput = $("input[name='Expenses[" + index + "].Name']");
                nameInput.remove();
                var idInput = $("input[name='Expenses[" + index + "].Id']");
                idInput.remove();

                // Remove the expense div from the view
                $(this).closest("div").remove();

                // Re-index the remaining expenses
                $("#expense-container > div").each(function (i) {
                    $(this).find("label").text("Expense " + (i + 1) + ":");
                    $(this).find("input[name^='Expenses']").each(function () {
                        var newName = $(this).attr("name").replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, "[" + i + "]");
                        $(this).attr("name", newName);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```